# What is the best way to check if my UIView has already been shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, didselectrowatindexpath

what is the best way to check if my UIView has already been shown on the screen. I have UISplitViewController in which I tried to display details in custom UIView after tap on tableViewCell. All I wanna do is to avoid duplication of the view that has already been displayed, or if possible closure of the present and display the new one.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"did select row at index path %ld",(long)indexPath.row );
InvoiceDetailsVC *detailsVC = [[InvoiceDetailsVC alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(321, 0,708, 709)];

 //here I would like to check if my detailsVC has already been shown 
 //if not I would like to display in that way
 [self.splitViewController.view addSubview:detailsVC];
}
```

Thanks for any help
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is best way to do this..

```
if ( _pageViewController.isViewLoaded && _pageViewController.view.window)
{
     NSLog(@"View is on screen");
}
```

Because `view.window` is only value if view is appeared on screen.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I try to load UIView instead of UIViewController. InvoiceDetailsVC is a custom uiview. So this methods are not visible for my custom uiview. In my storyboard I added UISplitViewController as a tabBarItem of UITabBarController and because of the fact that I can't communicate with detailsViewController because splitviewcontroleller must be at the root of the appliacation. I try to display details of selected UITAbleviewCell as a subview of splitviewcontroller. Is there any other solution for my question?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to override willMoveToSuperview: to keep this internal.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to override this method?

Comment: Simply create a subclass of the UIView class you want, and implement that method. You do know how to create a subclass and override a method I assume?

Comment: I'm sorry but I've never done such a thing, I'm beginner of objective-c.

Comment: or show me an example of that if it is not a problem for you?

Comment: Well in that case I think you should take a step back andearn a bit more about object oriented programming.

Comment: Which topic should I read especially to find the answer for override this method?

Comment: In general https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210 and specifically https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html (try to make sure you fully grasp the concept of 'subclassing', the cornerstone of object oriented design).

Comment: Thank you for your help Joride

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an `InvoiceDetailsVC` object everytime the user taps on a table row, so that view will always be not visible at that point. You may want to store a reference to the currently selected row/indexPath in `self.splitviewController` and check if the user is tapping the same `row/indexPath`.
Note that the Table DataSource (i.e. an array) must be static, or you should be updating the reference to the currently selected `row/indexPath` accordingly.

For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"did select row at index path %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    if ([self.splitViewController.currentlySelectedIndexPath compare:indexPath] != NSOrderedSame) {

        InvoiceDetailsVC *detailsVC = [[InvoiceDetailsVC alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(321, 0,708, 709)];
        [self.splitViewController.view addSubview:detailsVC];

        // Update reference to currently selected row/indexpath
        self.splitViewController.currentlySelectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    } else {
        // The currently visible view is the same. Do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **window** property of **UIView**.
If it is not already added , it will return **nil**

Above should work, if not
create a class property and use it as a flag to check whether your detailsVC is already added to screen or not.

For example,
In InvoiceDetailsVC.h header file or in .m file, add below code

```
@property BOOL addedToScreen;
```

in viewDidLoad of your viewcontroller

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
//your code above
self.addedToScreen =NO;
}
```

And finally in your didselectRow

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(self.addedToScreen== NO){
      InvoiceDetailsVC *detailsVC = [[InvoiceDetailsVC alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(321, 0,708, 709)];
      [self.splitViewController.view addSubview:detailsVC];
      self.addedToScreen =YES;
    }
 }
```

hope this helps,